# GestureDetector using Service

Tags: java, android, service

i wish to implement the `GestureDetector` using service instead of activity. the code works on activity but not on service. In `Service` i am not able to `@Override` the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` method - is this the cause of the problem?

```
public class GestureService extends Service implements OnGestureListener {

private GestureDetector gestureScanner;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();       
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;

 }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onSingleTapUp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

i started the service in an activity class using `startService(new Intent(this,GestureService.class));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to make it a Service so that you can use it for all applications.  But from reading [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html), it's really not the way it works: gestures are application specific.

Comment: ok. if i managed to get `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` called, beside getting the x and y coordinate of the event, what other information can i get? i.e the action. i tried `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` but it seems it dont return true when i touch the screen